# What am I doing wrong? Date comparison

Tags: unity, c#

There's this one precious little if in my code that is not doing what I want him to do.

Language is written in C# and doing it in Unity

Basically, I put a date on the Inputfield, which is linked to: BonoFinish, as soon as BonoFinish reaches DateTime.Now, it should appear a new gameobject, problem is... it does crap. What am I missing? Here's the code:

```
if (BonoFinish ==  DateTime.Now) 
    {

        PagPrincipal.SetActive (false);

        print (DateTime.Now);

        Bonos.SetActive (true);

        Debug.Log ("funciona");

        Invoke ("apagaBonos", 30f);
    }
```

Also, Bonofinish is written like this:
 `BonoFinish = DateTime.ParseExact (HoraBono.text, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` returns a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx). This is an object that represents both a date *and* a time. Equality comparison will naturally check both the date and time portions, and the time portion has millisecond accuracy.

That means that comparison will only ever be true for exactly one millisecond, so it's very unlikely you will ever *see* it be true. One iteration of a game loop can easily be several milliseconds long and cause you to skip the point in time where "now" precisely equals your stored date; even if you only parse your stored date out to minute resolution, there are still values in the second and millisecond fields (they're 0).

Chances are you only want to compare the date and time down to a more reasonable granularity, such as (perhaps) *just* the date. You can do this by comparing the components you care about directly:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
if(now.Year == BonoFinish.Year && now.Month == BonoFinish.Month...)
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this and update you on the matter

Answer (score 1):

Josh Petrie's answer is good in and of itself, but accessing different components of `Datetime.Now` and the `BonoFinish` object that many times might create a bottleneck point. A better way of doing the check would be to subtract them from each other, and then check whether the remaining time is good for you.

```
 var datetimetoday = DateTime.Today;
 var datetimenow = DateTime.Now;
 print(datetimenow - datetimetoday);
 print((datetimenow - datetimetoday).Hours);
 if((DateTime.Now - DateTime.Today).Hours>10)
 {
     print("This code works!");
 }
```

Right now (at hour 14:24 for my local time) this code gives the following results:

> 14:23:28.3691344 //(That's hours:minutes:seconds.ticks)
>
> 14
>
> This code works!

You have also gotten rid of possibly 6 combined if statements and made them into a subtraction (which actually uses ticks, so it's a one-off calculation) and an if statement.

Comment: I see you are making conscious effort to improve the quality of your answers. In case you were interested, I've taken to using [ScreenToGIF](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/) to record proofs to upload as .GIFs. Can sometimes make it far easier to get the point across, or quickly show how something works.

Comment: Alright, I'll see about using that in the future. Thanks Genmlock :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Josh's code, this is definitely because it is comparing the time components. You can eliminate the time component in a number of ways. I find using `DateTime.Date` more succinct:

```
if (BonoFinish.Date ==  DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    //Your code
}
```

This equates the 2 dates with a time of `00:00:00`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood where the problem is, if you are having troubles getting inside the If statement, or you can get in but your GameObject doesn't spawn.

In the first case, try to Debug on console both BonoFinish and DateTime.Now to be sure they are the same, and in case, why they do not match. ParseExact is a very precise function and it is expecting a valid input format (which you seem to be providing), the only test you can make are about HoraBono.text and if its input is well-formatted and recognized by the function.

In the second case, assuming that you can reach "Debug.Log ("funciona")", two possible things can cause the object not to spawn: 1) there is an error inside apagaBonos function, or you are not actually "ticking" 30 seconds. This can be due to a lot of factors, for example you could be calling this code inside an Editor script.

Comment: It doesn't reach the "funciona: debug.log.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it. It could be that maybe I linked the wrong text to the input field. LEt me see if that's the case

Comment: Nope, everything is well linked